# Getting individual array elements from the data returned by a chainlink external adapter

Tags: chainlink

In the job I'm adding for my external adapter, I'm looking to get results for the first 3 elements in the `Results` array one at a time.(see the data returned from my external adapter below)

So I'm adding "position" to my chainlink request in the consumer contract and wanting to use that in the `jsonparse` like below, rather than pass it to the external adapter. However, I get this error `JSONParse task error: $(decode_cbor.position) is not a valid array index`

````
parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,MRData,RaceTable,Races,0,Results,$(decode_cbor.position),number" data="$(fetch)"]```
````

in my consumer contract

```
Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
request.add("position", "1");
```

The data returned from the external adapter looks like this.

```
{
    "MRData": {
        "xmlns": "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4",
        "series": "f1",
        "url": "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json",
        "limit": "30",
        "offset": "0",
        "total": "20",
                
        "RaceTable": {
            "season": "2021",
            "round": "17",
        
          "Races": [{
                "season": "2021",
                "round": "17",
                "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_United_States_Grand_Prix",
                "raceName": "United States Grand Prix",
                "Circuit": {
                    "circuitId": "americas",
                    "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_of_the_Americas",
                    "circuitName": "Circuit of the Americas",
                    "Location": {
                        "lat": "30.1328",
                        "long": "-97.6411",
                        "locality": "Austin",
                        "country": "USA"
                    }
                },
                "date": "2021-10-24",
                "time": "19:00:00Z",
        
                "Results": [{
                    "number": "33",
                    "position": "1",
                    "positionText": "1",
                    "points": "25",
                    "Driver": {
                        "driverId": "max_verstappen",
                        "permanentNumber": "33",
                        "code": "VER",
                        "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Verstappen",
                        "givenName": "Max",
                        "familyName": "Verstappen",
                        "dateOfBirth": "1997-09-30",
                        "nationality": "Dutch"
                    },.....
```

The full results can be found here. http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json

Should I be able to do something like this? Is there a better way to go about this? Should I edit the adapter instead?

```
schemaVersion = 1
name = "f1latestresults2"
contractAddress = "0x765aCc258f3a7b2D8d103D1A9310fc51b07D5425"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]

    fetch        [type=bridge name="raceresults" requestData="{\\"id\\":$(jobSpec.externalJobID),\\"data\\":{\\"position\\":\\"0\\"}}"]
    

    parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,MRData,RaceTable,Races,0,Results,$(decode_cbor.position),number" data="$(fetch)"]

    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0x765aCc258f3a7b2D8d103D1A9310fc51b07D5425" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "cfa059b4-a31d-4c30-99e4-3a2fd4c57739"
```

Comment: Can you add the full TOML job spec?

Comment: Added above thanks. 
note I'm passing the position to the external adapter even though it doesn't need it becuase I haven't worked out how to make the fetch without passing some data as it errors out when I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using looks correct to me, so I'm not 100% sure if the TOML jobs can support having a parameter like that within a string yet?

If the rest of the JSON path is static, suggest just having it as a built up string in your consuming contract, and just sending it as a full string in the request, then using that in your TOML spec, similar to the example [in the docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/)

```
req.add("path", "data,MRData,RaceTable,Races,0,Results,0");
```

Then in your TOML job spec:

```
parse        [type=jsonparse path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]
```

Comment: Thank you that should make it nice and simple.